# How to get the correct build of react-beautiful-dnd library?

Tags: reactjs, rollupjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I did a fork for react-beautiful-dnd github project and I added some features
but when I build my fork using  `yarn run build` and use the new dist in my project I get a compile issue

```
./node_modules/suivi-beautiful-dnd-with-custom-payload/dist/react-beautiful-dnd.esm.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './view/drag-drop-context/index.js' in 'C:\Users\tahas\OneDrive\Bureau\Backend\Statsh\Statsh.Frontend_POC\node_modules\suivi-beautiful-dnd-with-custom-payload\dist'
```

I saw that there is a difference between **my build in npm** and the **build provided by react-beautiful-dnd npm** but I did not figure out why I'm getting a difference or I didn't change the build config in package.json file ?

**Screenshot of my npm build :**

[image]

**Screenshot of the build provided by react-beautiful-dnd npm :**

[image]

How to solve that issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I did my own boilerplate to build the project and it works now !**
https://github.com/ProNoob702/Boilerplate-to-build-custom-react-beautiful-dnd